# calculate mean of raster in webmapping application

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet, geoserver

I'm trying to develop a GIS web application. I'm using raster image.  I need to calculate the mean of image geotiff. I am using html javascript ,geoserver , leaflet  and i didn't found the way  to do this.

```
<script>

// Instantiation de différentes couches provenant de GeoServer

                var urbanareas = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
                    layers: 'cite:GIOVANNI-wmsLayer_p06NTXAh',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    transparent: true
                });

        var grayscale = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
                    layers: 'cite:COMGEO',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    transparent: true
                });
//var grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: mbAttr}),
    //streets  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets',   attribution: mbAttr});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [34.08,-5.00],
    zoom:6,
    layers: [grayscale, urbanareas]
});

var baseLayers = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale
    //"Streets": streets
};

var overlays = {
    "prepitation": urbanareas
};
```

Answer (score 1):

By "the mean" you mean you have a GeoTiff with some actual values, e.g., an elevation, and need to compute the average value in a given area, or whole raster?

There are two "raster zonal statistics"  processes in GeoServer WPS that can do something similar, although it's more sophisticated than what you need, it's going to compute min/max/avg/stddev of the values of a raster on a set of polygons (e.g., admin boundaries).

Unfortunately I don't have documentation for them or a sample request, honestly for what you're trying to do I'd try to derive a simpler version of the process in Java code.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i have a geotiff with true values of precipitation   and i need to calculate the mean of precipitation in a given area chosen  by the user (e.g overage  region )

Comment: Yes, as said, I'd build a new process either deriving it from the zonal statistics, or writing a new one

Comment: have  you any documentation can help me , i found gdal bibothèque but i dont no how  use it !